# $\int \lambda d E_\lambda^A \cdot \int( 1/\lambda) \chi_{(0,\infty)} d E_\lambda^A =?$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

Let $A$ be a positive operator acting on a Hilbert space  $H$. Let $$ A=\int \lambda d E_\lambda^A$$
be the spectral decomposition.
Define $B:=\int (1/\lambda) \chi_{(0,\infty)} d E_\lambda ^A$. Then, clearly, $B$ can be unbounded. 
I would like to ask do we have $AB = s(A)$ (the support of $A$)? or do we have $AB\le s(A)$.

Comment: The domain of $B$ is $\{ x : \int \frac{1}{\lambda^2}d\|E_{\lambda}^{A}x\|^2 < \infty \}$, which doesn't generally coincide with the support of $A$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts  So, less than the support?

Comment: If $A$ is unbounded, then the domain of $A$ consists of all $x$ for which $\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^2 d\|E_{\lambda}^Ax\|^2 < \infty$. So there are differences near $\lambda=0$ and near $\lambda=\infty$, generally with opposite inclusions near the two extremes.